# How do I undo a gem install that messed up my Rails app?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I installed a gem to make my URLs case-insensitive but I'm seeing a lot of broken links. Instead of going through and trying to fix them, I'd rather just undo the install I did.

If I ran `gem uninstall gemname`, will that make my Rails app return to how it was before?

Comment: I just wanted to be cautious and not mess it up even more

Comment: You can remove gems, and re-add them all day long. Ruby might complain when it can't find a gem you've required in your code, but the fix would be to reinstall it or remove the `require`. If you're requiring it as part of a Rails app, or via Bundler, you'll need to remove it from your Gemfile, but again, nothing drastic will happen, you'll just get an error message telling you so. No fires will break out (usually) and rarely does it cause power-outages (any more). Just work backwards through the steps you followed to install it and all should be fine.

Comment: Help us help you by telling what that gem is.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to remove the gem from your `Gemfile`.  Check your `Gemfile.lock` as well to see what dependencies the gem had.

Of course if you referenced the gem anywhere in your app you'll need to remove those references as well.

Comment: looks like all references to it in the Gemfile.lock disappeared as well so hopefully I'm clean